# Support for JDBC 4.2?

Tags: db2, jdbc, db2-luw

As far as I can tell, the jcc driver shipped with 11.5 (https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/db2-jdbc-driver-versions-and-downloads) still uses JDBC 4.1. Any rumours of, if a later fixpak will switch to JDBC 4.2 ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/jdbc_42.html )? I'm primarily interested in the change in date/time handling.

Comment: You will have to ask IBM that

Comment: And guess what will be the answer.

Comment: I already figured out that I won't get an official answer, that's why I asked for any unconfirmed rumours. DST causes a bunch of problems with the current DATE implementation

Comment: FWIW, the driver shipped with 11.5.8 appears to support localdate